# Mono missing X509CertificateCollection ClientCertificates in Unity3d, is there a way to add it with a library or asset?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, mono

I am wondering if there are any assets or libraries out there that can add some needed functionality that Mono seems to be missing in regards to using X509 client certificates. I am getting this error :

```
NotImplementedException: The method or operation is not implemented. at
System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.get_ClientCertificates () [0x00000] in <20a8f293e89843148f03a963627efba4>:0 
at Raven.Client.Http.RequestExecutor.CreateHttpMessageHandler 
(System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2 certificate, 
System.Boolean setSslProtocols, System.Boolean useCompression, System.Boolean 
hasExplicitlySetCompressionUsage) [0x00075] in <3af6f962c10f46e297126f8db0cace22>:0
```

Looking through Monos github, line 429 of System.Net.Http/System.Net.Http/HttpClientHandler.cs shows this, unfortunately.

```
    public X509CertificateCollection ClientCertificates 
    {
        get {
            throw new NotImplementedException ();
        }
    }
```

So I was hoping that perhaps someone might know of something out there that might be able to give me the missing functionality that I am needing?

Thanks for any assistance you are able to provide!
-MH

Comment: `HttpClientHandler` has many derived classes. When `HttpClientHandler` does not meet your expectation, switch to others such as `WebRequestHandler` [here](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/0bcbe39b148bb498742fc68416f8293ccd350fb6/mcs/class/System.Net.Http.WebRequest/System.Net.Http.WebRequest/WebRequestHandler.cs) or any other Unity supports.

Comment: I definitely appreciate that, I am going to see if this is something I can work with for the DB. Might need them to make a patch or something, but it might end up ok then.  Thanks!